# How to write http protocol client with only GET and POST methods in C or C++

Tags: c++, c, http, client, protocols

So my question is: How to write http protocol client with only GET and POST methods in C or C++. Thank you for your answers

Comment: get some library or read RFC 2616...

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/). If you want to implement an own http client library, you can build it on top of [Boost ASIO](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html). Both libraries work fine on Linux and Windows platforms.

Answer (score 1):

Depends a bit on level of sanity you expect to experience in the unforeseeable future.

The sane/chicken way out would be to use a [library](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/). The insane/fun way would be to write it from scratch. By this I mean it is, (should be), lots of fun to write, but at the same time there is a lot of libraries out there. Of course, for educational purposes the *fun way* is absolutely doable, and thanks to the RFC community in large part a pleasant task.

1. Learn sockets.
2. Read the [HTTP 0.9](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/AsImplemented.html) and [HTTP 1.0 (RFC 1945)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1945) specs for fun.
3. Read, re-read, re-re-read and implement [HTTP 1.1 (RFC 2616)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616).

Which parts of the standard to implement to fulfill *only* GET and POST methods is best revealed by reading the RFC. In short – it is a lot.

- Properly format a request-URI.
- Properly handle various request options like *If-**, *Range* etc.
- Properly handle redirects etc.
- Properly handle dates, compression, chunked message, keep-alives, status codes, …
- … *at the end most of the standard is covered.*